# The multi-part identifier "abc@abc.com" could not be bound. in MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that receives one parameter @Value VARCHAR(8000). When I try to execute this stored with an email_id value I get the error mentioned above.
The code is something like that:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[check] @Value VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

And the execute command is:

```
EXEC [dbo].[check] @Value = 'abc@abc.com';
```

The problem is obvious with MS SQL reading the dot in the value as multi-part although the value is surrounded by a single quote. I can of course surround the value with another two set of single quotes (e.g. '''abc@abc.com''') and remove the extra quotes in the stored procedure but is there any better method to achieve the same?

Comment: Does the proc use dynamic SQL? That shouldn't cause that error and can't reproduce it after creating this proc `CREATE PROC [dbo].[check] @Value varchar(1000) AS SELECT 'OK'`

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't show the most important information: the code. I'm guessing somewhere you have dynamic SQL with something like this: `set @sql = 'SELECT...WHERE SomeColumn = ' + @Value`?